# Divergence of power series at the edge

Tags: real-analysis, limits, power-series

Let $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ be a power series with radius of convergence $R \in (0,\infty)$ and $a_n \ge 0$ for all $n$.

Show that if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n R^n = \infty$ then 
$\lim_{x \nearrow R} \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n = \infty$.

The theorem sounds intuitive but I don't know how to approach a proof. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Use the theorem of the iterated limit on $R \in \overline{\left]-R,R\right[}$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $M>0$. Since $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nR^n=+\infty$, there is a $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^Na_nR^n>M$. Therefore$$\tag1\lim_{x\to R^-}\sum_{n=0}^Na_nx^n=\sum_{n=0}^Na_nR^n>M.$$Since each $a_n$ is a non-negative real,$$\tag2\bigl(\forall x\in[0,R)\bigr):\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n\geqslant\sum_{n=0}^Na_nx^n.$$It follows from $(1)$ and $(2)$ that$$\lim_{x\to R^-}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n=+\infty.$$

Comment: Sorry for asking probably a dumb question, but I don't understand how your proof has showed the statement. Maybe it's because I don't understand what is to prove about the statement in the first place. To me it seems like the conditions already are the result, i.e. $\sum a_n R^n = \infty$ is (?) the same as $\lim_{x \to R^-} \sum a_n x_n$.

Comment: @philmcole Note that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n$ does not exist, but $\lim_{x\to1^-}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nx^n=\frac12$. So, yes, there is something that must be proved. And what I did shows that, if $M>0$, then, if $x$ is close enough to (and smaller than) $R$, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n>M$, which means that $\lim_{x\to R^-}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n=+\infty$.